# I am new to react and wanted to have functions/buttons from one file to have effects on contents in another file. So, what is the way to do so?

Tags: reactjs

```
            <button
              className="ui inverted button"
              disabled={false}
              onClick={this.nextQuestionHandler}
            >
              Next Question
            </button>
          )}
```

Here, I have used next Question button in Question.js file, what I want is after clicking on next Question button in Question.js file it should have effect in content of another files,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have one file (called the parent) that contains both files and store the states and functions inside that file and pass them to your children files so when you press the button in the child component it triggers the reference in the parent component. [Read more](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

[Here's a photo for better demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkx10.png)

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the answer, it was much needed!

Comment: @Vedant no problem! please mark answer as accepted if it helped.